# How to connect realtime script to gamelift local sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-gamelift

I am trying to setup gamelift,For testing integration I started gamelift local which instantiate amazon game services here are the logs

```
  17:50:53,460  INFO || - [SocketIOServer] main - Session store / pubsub 
  factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
  17:50:54,460  WARN || - [ServerBootstrap] main - Unknown channel option 
  'SO_LINGER' for channel '[id: 0xc9982980]'
  17:50:54,467  INFO || - [SocketIOServer] nioEventLoopGroup-2-1 - SocketIO 
  server started at port: 5757
  17:50:54,467  INFO || - [SDKConnection] main - GameLift SDK server 
  (communicates with your game server) has started on http://localhost:5757
  17:50:54,501  INFO || - [StandAloneServer] main - GameLift Client server 
  (listens for GameLift client APIs) has started on http://localhost:9080
```

Now i don't know how to establish connection with my realtime script at port 5757.

I have tried using

```
  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5757', true)
  request.onload = function () {
    Init();
    console.log("server initialised")
  }
```

it wont even ping the gamelift local.

Please help how to establish connection.